# How should I re-create this design in HTML and CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a little sage advice from some helpful HTML/CSS masters.  I am in the process of building a website to help people in my area find an apartment.  I've been working with a friend of mine who does graphics design and he created some really nice looking mockups that I am now working on implementing in HTML/CSS.

I attached an image of the filters and I was wondering how I should create them.  If I use CSS to style the pill shaped inputs, it probably won't work on all browsers.  Should I take the approach of creating small, repeating blue lines that form the background of the inputs?

I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me, but I was wondering if anyone has advice on taking a CSS or image based approach to building a design that looks like the attached mockup.

[image: mocked up input elements]

Comment: Backgrounds can just be stretched.

Comment: @Dave Newton — Assuming you are happy for it to only work on browsers implementing that feature of CSS 3 and for the curves to be of different lengths on different buttons as they scale based on the width of the button.

Comment: @Quentin The ends are separate images.

Comment: @Dave — then the borders will be different widths.

Comment: @Quentin I don't understand why you think that. Although I meant repeated, not stretched, stretching horizontally wouldn't change anything vertically.

Comment: @Dave Newton — I thought that because you said stretched.

Comment: @Quentin As I said, I mis-spoke--it happens occasionally. But stretching horizontally wouldn't scale anything vertically, so I still don't see how any borders would be different widths.

Comment: @Dave There are borders on the horizontal edges too.

Comment: @Quentin If you scale something horizontally, the top and bottom doesn't change. We're talking past each other; carry on.

Comment: @Dave There is a blue border on the left and right edges of each button. If that scales from 1 to 2 pixels it makes a big difference.

Comment: @Quentin But those would be images; I'm talking about the background that doesn't change--the parts immediately behind the text. Since they're individually selectable, they're obviously different "segments".

Comment: this is not really a programming question is it? but since I can't think of a better suited stackoverflow site for this nice question I'll upvote it anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your audience. I target only the latest browsers, so I choose the latest CSS. Almost anything is possible in CSS. If you must support older browsers, use JS as a fallback.

Here's what I did in pure CSS in about 20 mins. Of course it could be much better, but I didn't want to spend any more time on it, just wanted to get you started if you decide to go that way.

[image]

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/PHTsb/

HTML:

```
<div id="bedrooms" class="button">
    <div id="walking">Walking</div>
    <div class="body">Bedroom</div>
    <div class="count">1</div>
    <div class="down">&#x25bc;</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Satisfy);

body
{
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAMAAAADCAYAAABWKLW/AAAAGklEQVQI12Pw8fH5X19fD8YMMAZIkAHGANEAiZwUkmznO8QAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
}

#bedrooms
{
width: 146px;        
}

.button
{
background-color: #65c3e6;
background-image: linear-gradient( 
    top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .0 ) 60%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 
    top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .0 ) 60%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 
    top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .0 ) 60%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient( 
    top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .0 ) 60%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 
    top, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .4 ) 0%, rgba( 255, 255, 255, .0 ) 60%);
border-bottom: 1px solid #4998b8;
border-radius: 22px;
border-top: 1px solid #cbeef7;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(71,71,71,.65);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(71,71,71,.65);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(71,71,71,.65);
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(71,71,71,.65);
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(71,71,71,.65);
color: white;
height: 36px;
margin: 30px 0 0 30px;
position: relative;
}

#walking
{
font: bold 24px Satisfy;
left: -17px;
letter-spacing: -2px;
position: absolute;
text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(69,69,69,.2), -1px 1px 1px rgba(69,69,69,.1);
top: -13px;
transform:rotate(-15deg);
-webkit-transform:rotate(-15deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(-15deg);
-o-transform:rotate(-15deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-15deg);
}

.body
{
border-right: 1px solid #73c7e6;
display: inline-block;
font: normal 24px/24px Yanone Kaffeesatz;
height: 30px;
margin-left: 10px;
padding: 6px 8px 0 0;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(69,69,69,.2), -1px 1px 1px rgba(69,69,69,.1);
text-transform: uppercase; 
vertical-align: top;
}

.count
{
border-left: 1px solid #8fd4eb;
color: #185269;    
display: inline-block;
font: bold 16px/16px Helvetica, Arial;
height: 25px;
padding: 11px 6px 0 8px;
margin-left: 1px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
vertical-align: top;
}

.down
{
color: #42778c;    
display: inline-block;
font: normal 14px/14px Helvetica, Arial;
height: 24px;
padding-top: 12px;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), -1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.2);
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Though in FF on Win 7 the down arrow drops out of the button. Bumping the width of bedrooms to 160px fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't do any testing on other browsers, so bound to be some tweaks needed. I changed it to 160px in the demo. Thanks!

Comment: wow, this is great!  I was not expecting such a complete answer with code and such.  I can definitely modify this to my liking.  I think I will go the CSS route and gracefully degrade for IE.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wlindner only other suggestion I'd make is to have a look at google fonts for your script style font for "walking". http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the browser support.

So I wouldn't go the CSS route with this.

I would make the left and right rounded borders and make them into images.

I also would create a `1px` width image of the background and repeat this horizontally (`repeat-x`).

Answer (score 0):

CSS support is very strong in Firefox 4.X+, Chrome and Safari. It's even reasonable in IE 8 and IE 9. Your best bet might be to start from CSS and use JavaScript to clean up the UI if IE 6 or 7 is detected. By this point, it's fairly safe to assume that anyone not using IE 6 or 7 is using a modern browser.

Comment: Well IE8 can't do rounded corners or box shadows or (good) gradient backgrounds ...

Comment: I would use CSS as Mike recommended and gracefully degrade for IE.

Comment: @Mike Thomsen: I have to agree with Pointy on this one. Also you say: `It's even reasonable in IE 8 and IE 9` I would use `reasonable AT BEST` :-)

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I'd go with images unless you're really good at CSS.

But as an aside, they're some good looking buttons.

Comment: I don't think this is about how good someone is with CSS. But rather the browser support to do things IMHO.

Comment: You could get this working with CSS (and some JS) if you knew what you were doing.

Comment: Sure you can. I will never say it isn't possible to achieve this with CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

While not a master myself, I'm going to suggest  that your question is:  how to best get a psd to html / css.

I am currently reading  Sitepoint's free ebook book  "[thinking the web](http://www.sitepoint.com/thinking-web-voices-of-the-community/)"  on a chapter on this topic (chapter 5).  The author suggested that you 1) know your target audience (what browsers are they using) and two make a choice.  css3 can rounded corners that will not break on older / other browsers but not be a pretty.   So this can be a great choice if a majority of your visitors will be using modern browsers.

ps. I'm not employed / associated with sitepoint either.